# AngularJS, ng-model slow because other watchers are slow

Tags: angularjs, performance, angular-ngmodel

I have a simple `ng-model` for example:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="active" />
```

And I have a watcher like:

```
<pre>Status = <span ng-bind="value()"></span></pre>
```

The watcher is very slow because whatever reason and it makes the above form element to react also slow what makes the interface to look clumsy.

Of course I have to make an effort in optimise the bellow bind element but the point is that I don't really need this element to be fast, I need the form element to be fast because this is the one the User is putting attention.

So how can I make the `ng-model` to have priority over the other watcher?

To reproduce the issue you can visit **[this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xqBsKzJoP7EukwhhSor7?p=preview)**. Check the `app.js` where you can see the method `value()` has been artificially delayed, you can manipulate this delay to increase the effect.

Comment: You could make that operation async, or perform whatever operation you are doing in ng-change function (I am not sure what you are actually doing assuming it is associated with the change of checkbox). Reason is simple when your watchers run it will run the ng-bind expression as well, which takes tie so the entire update of all watchers in the digest cycle will take time. http://jsbin.com/wawuzucimo/1/edit Or http://jsbin.com/pugorovedo/4/edit

Comment: There is only one digest loop. One really slow watchExpression is enough to make the entire loop slow. You are probably better off by removing the slow watchExpression and handle it outside of Angulars digest loop.